# How to find a staff member profile

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, stack-exchange-team

I tried to complete my [Winter/Summer Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-bash), but then a question came up...

Yes, I did visit some top moderators user data profiles, but nothing happened...

**[Behind the Curtain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384707/winter-summer-bash-2022-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F-%EF%B8%8F/384708#384708)**

> View the profile of a staff member.

Comment: Is it specific for this year? Then there is the [winter-bash-2022  tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2022).

Comment: I agree there's some bug there. I discovered a profile of Catija who has the "Staff" badge, but no hat thing happened - so far, at least :( https://stackoverflow.com/users/4548692/catija ; https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33128/catija

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the uber-Meta a similar question was asked a few Winter bashes ago: [Who are the users that work for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95625/who-are-the-users-that-work-for-stack-overflow)

That question has several answers, one of which is mine. It states:

> It turns out there is a [`/users/moderators`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderators#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint *[on the Stack API]* which returns moderators (diamonds) and if we filter the ones with `is_employee === true` we can build that (somewhat incomplete) list of users that are staff.

In [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304217) you'll find the runnable Stack Snippet and that will list employees from around the network. You only need to click one to earn the badge.

An alternative is searching for specific tagged posts. On Meta Staff will post questions with the tag [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) or [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery). Needs a bit of clicking and skipping users that are no longer employed by SE. For nerds, like myself, I created a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1690815) to achieve something similar.